# Is it easy to abuse the observer pattern?

Tags: ruby, oop, observer-pattern

I have a project where I am using the observer pattern extensively for the first time.  One thing I've found though, is that if I inspect a typical object in this project, it tends to be astonishingly large with all of the observers and observables, and then the times when an observer has other observers, etc.

That seems to be be beside the point since the performance is fine.  But I've found that occasionally when I'm in the debugger, if I try to print an instance variable that it will lock up my machine until I kill the process.  This has me concerned that there is some opportunity for this to happen while the code is in production.  Or that this is just a warning that I am abusing the pattern.

Any tips, suggestions?

Comment: Well, you should only be using it when you need it, versus for all of your objects even when they don't need to be notified of changes/events.

Comment: Maybe the biggest issue I'm having is that it makes it harder to debug my code with the non linearity of events firing.  And the fact that it's locking up my debugger is not helping.

Comment: @CloseVoters: The question's a bit general, but it is worthwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Yep, but that doesn't mean it's not perfect sometimes.

"Astonishingly large" implies... it's pretty large; what does that *actually* mean? How many observers/observables are there? Are they deeply nested?

IMO the correlation between doing stuff in a debugger and "real life" isn't particularly strong; *has* it ever locked up in production or testing? I'd be more likely to think it's an artifact of the debugging process/app.

"Spooky action at a distance" creates non-locality that must be understood in order to reason correctly about code and behavior. This kind of development needs to be groomed aggressively; rather than saying "I'll just create a new observer", architect it in, and keep reasoning as linear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `inspect` method to be less verbose.